# Error decompressing some GZIP strings - java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths

Tags: java, character-encoding, gzip

I'm trying to convert a gzipped byte string into an uncompressed string. On nearly every input, it works properly without error. However, some byte strings cause the aforementioned ZipException. I am able to successfully decompress these byte strings in python, but the following java code which attempts to do the same decompression fails with an 'invalid stored block lengths' issue.

The error seems to occur on the 'IOUtils.toByteArray' bit, which makes me think perhaps it uses some incompatible encoding?

```
    public static String unZipPayloadToString(ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException {
        GZIPInputStream gzp = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.array()));
        return new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(gzp), "UTF-8");
    }
```

Here's the stack trace.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:721)
    at com.expedia.processor.processAvroData.unZipPayloadToString(processAvroData.java:130)
    at com.expedia.processor.processAvroData.deserializeBatch(processAvroData.java:54)
    at com.expedia.gfo.LambdaAvroToText.handleRequest(LambdaAvroToText.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoMethodRequestHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:280)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:197)
    at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:897)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:228)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:162)
    at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.main(AWSLambda.java:157)
```

Comment: Where are you getting this gzipped data from? Can you give an example of some data that causes it to fail? Have you tried logging the problematic data?

Comment: The data doesn't seem to be problematic - I used standard python library gzip to decompress the exact same data, and it succeeded in decompressing. The data is made up of many lines of JSON.

Comment: You got the data out of the ByteBuffer, saved it off, then ran it through python? I doubt that. No one can possibly help you debug the problem if you don't provide any data, or at least show how the data is getting into your program.

Comment: Okay - I start with an avro file. I convert the avro file into JSON. One of the fields in the avro file contains a bytestring, which is the gzipped byte buffer I'm trying to decompress.